# How to make sure at least one select box from multiple select boxes has a value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a dynamic form where the user can add multiple select boxes:

```
<form id="ticket_form">
  <select class="required" name="quantity[1]"></select>
  <select class="required" name="quantity[2]"></select>
  <select class="required" name="quantity[3]"></select>
</form>
```

At the moment, I'm making sure that the user has chosen a value for each select boxes:

```
$("#ticket_form").validate({
  rules: {
    'quantity[]': 'required'
  },
  messages: {
    'quantity[]': 'This field is whack'
  }
});
```

I only actually need to have one of them to have a selected value. What should I do to let the validation pass when at least one of the select boxes has a value?

**UPDATE**

This is the code that I ended up with to solve my problem as per Ben Barden's solution:

```
$.validator.addMethod("groupSelect", (function(value, element, isRunning) {
  return $(".required[value!=\"\"]").length > 0;
}), "At least one must be selected.");
```

I also added an additional class rule to the `required` class, so I don't have to add any more to the actual validation rules:

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
  'required': {
    'groupSelect': true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you're pretty much going to have to create your own validation rule, but the rule you need is pretty simple.  All members of that class will validate if there exists any member of that class with a value other than the default.  Thus,  you use the class selector, then filter further by the value not-equals selector, and check if the result contains anything.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "groupSelect",
    function (value, element, isRunning)
    {
        return $('.groupSelectClass[value!="defaultSelectValue"]').length > 0;
    },
    "At least one must be selected.");
```

then just apply the `groupSelect` rule (the one written there) to the `groupSelectClass` class (which you make sure is added to all of your selectors on generation) and ensure that whatever you have in place of `defaultSelectValue` is actually the default value for the selectors.  Note that this all needs to be set up before the base `validate` call, not after.

Edit:

Further explanation: the above block of code defines a validation rule by the name of `groupSelect` (or whatever you put there).  As written, the `groupSelect` rule returns valid if and only if at least one of the nodes with the class "groupSelectClass" has some value other than "defaultSelectValue".  If you make sure that everything with the class "groupSelectClass" is a select box with a default value of "defaultSelectValue", then this rule will return valid if and only if at least one of those select boxes has been set.  If you then apply this rule to the "groupSelect" class using the `jQuery.validator.addClassRules` function, it will cause all of those select boxes to have that as a validation requirement, and display "At least one must be selected." on validation failure.  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules should give you enough understanding of how to use the addClassRules function.  Indeed, I'd recommend you read up on the stuff in that site in general, particularly the validation plugin information, if you're going to be doing much with it.

Comment: I think this is what I need, but I can't understand the answer completely. Can you give more explanation?

Comment: more explanation has been provided.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the fact that you didn't provide the actual answer, but instead pointed me in the right direction. I'll be updating the question with the code that I ended up. I'll also be accepting your answer because this is the closest answer to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you liked it.  I will note that you may wish to use some class other than "required" for this part, though - "required" has special meaning for jquery validator and you may wish to use it elsewhere if you ever change the form.  Fortunately, jquery handles multiple classes on the same node just fine, with things like `class="required myclass"` being searchable off of both `.required` and `.myclass`, and using both sets of validation requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to check this but this is a non .validate() approach

```
function CheckValue(){
    var oneSelected = false;


     $('#ticket_form select').each(function(k,v){

          // this assumes that zero is an unselected index 
          if($(v).children('option:selected').val() != 0){

             oneSelected = true;

           }

     });

     return oneSelected;
}
```

Comment: Your `each`ing on an ID which wold make it invalid html. Are you sure that is what you meant? I guess you meant `$('.required')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = [];

$('.required').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val() != null) { // Check for null or undefined if not proceed
        index.push(i);
    }
});
```

index now has an array of indexes for your select boxes that have values. Access them with using `index[0]`, where 0 is the first matched select with a value.

```
var selectVal = $('.required').eq(index[0]).val();
```